# Mvc5 getting data list from controller to ajax function c#

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-ajax

i am getting data list from controller to ajax function to my datatable.all works well but my question is, I want to get one of list property to textbox and other values to datatable columns.for example:
list= TotalAMount,PAidAmount,RemAmount
and datatable 
Totalamount| PaidAMount | RemAmount|    ---------??
20         | 4          | 16       |

so this works fine but i want to get TotalAmount value to some textbox also like textbox=20.
my JS function==>>
` 
function AddGetHistoryView(SupplierID) {

```
            $('#HistoryModal').modal('show');

            Datatabless = $("#HistoryTable").DataTable({
                "autoWidth": false,


                "ajax": {
                    "type": "GET",

                    "url": "@Url.Action("getHistoryData", "Supplier")/" + SupplierID,
                    "datatype": "JSON",

                    data: {
                        "Amount": $("#TotalAmount").val()


                    },
                    data: { SupplierID: SupplierID },






                },


                "columns": [

                    {
                        "data": "DetailID",
                        "visible": false,

                    },
                    {
                        "data": "TotalAmount",

                        "width": "5%",
                    },

                    {
                        "data": "PaidAmount",
                        "width": "5%",
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "RemAmount",
                        "width": "5%",
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "PaidDate",
                        "width": "5%",

                    },
                    {
                        "data": "PaymentType",
                        "width": "5%",
                    },

                    {


                        "data": "DetailID", "render": function (data) {
                            return "<a class='btn btn-success' onclick=EditRow(" + data + ") style='margin-left:12px'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'>&nbsp;Update</i><a/>,<a class='btn btn-danger' onclick=deleteRow(" + data + ") style='margin-left:12px'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'>&nbsp;Delete</i> <a/>";

                        },

                        "width": "40%",
                        "orderable": false,

                        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                        "paging": true,


                    },



                ],





            });




        }
```

`
Controller Method==>

```
 public ActionResult getHistoryData(int SupplierID)
    {
        ob.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

        var data = ob.Table_Supplier.Join(ob.Table_SupplierDetails, sup => sup.SupplierID, det => det.SupplierID, (sup, det) => new
        {
            DetailID=det.DetailID,
            SupplierID = sup.SupplierID,
            TotalAmount = det.TotalAmount,
            RemAmount = det.RemAmount,
            PaidAmount = det.PaidAmount,
            PaidDate = det.PaidDate,
            PaymentType = det.PaymentType,
            Amount = sup.Amount


        }).Where(x=>x.SupplierID==SupplierID).ToList();


        return Json(new { data = data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: You have TotalAmount value in each record, do you want to get the value of a specific record to the textbox or sum of all TotalAmount values ?

Comment: thanks for reply sir. I am really dissappointed i see alot of replies in other posts bt when it come to mine no one replies ..Thanks again i jus want one record Total Amount value in that textbox not each record just one totalamount value

Comment: What value you want as TotalAmount ? 100 , 200 or something else ?

Comment: sir i am fetching 4records forexample totalamount,remainingamount,,paid amount,and name.  i am fetching all records to datatable except name..now i want that name to be in textbox..its not in datatble ..i hope u get my point

Comment: You are getting multiple records, each of them will have all those fields. which recors's specific TotalAmount you want ? Or you want the sum of all 4 ?

Comment: sir let me explain again i have two tables in database one is table supplier with column remainingAmount..2nd table named Table_SupplierDetails..when i click Table_supplier it fetches me record according to SupplierId in 2nd Datatble which has datat of supplier details with columns total  paid remaining..now my question is it fetches all records of table_supplier details...i want to fetch 1st table named Table_supplier property that is TotalAmount that has only single value 20dollars